# html2canvas - record animations inside parent div and render to canvas for export as video

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have multiple css3 animations running in child elements of a div. the animation is controlled using a javascript setInterval countTo value. for each update I am able to run the below code and generate dataURL png images:

```
let array_of_dataURL_image_strings = [];

html2canvas(document.querySelector("#parent_animation_div")).then(canvas => {
    let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
            
    array_of_dataURL_image_strings.push(image);
});
```

However the above code is not perfect in generating a complete smooth animation and sometimes it doesn't work properly.

What I want to do is,

capture each frame in the running animation and insert it into one single canvas as animation and later export as video/sequence of images.

or export the whole div animation into a video or sequence of images directly.

Comment: got any luck on this?

Comment: Not yet. I have opted for alternative solutions. Html5animationtogif.com. if you need a technical solution you can find a post here that uses node js:https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24912-websites-that-help-convert-html5-animations-to-video/